# Transform file doesn't work during import/export from/to RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I need to import/export some documents collection using filtering by substrings.

I tried:

```
raven.smuggler out http://localhost:8080/ dump.raven --database=Host1 --matadata-filter=Raven-Entity-Name=SagaUniqueIdentity --transform-file=testsaga.js
```

and then:

```
raven.smuggler in http://server8287:8080/ dump.raven --database=Host1 --transform-file=testsaga.js
```

However nothing changed whether I use `--transform-file` or not. I event tried non existed file name - still no errors and all data exported.

My testsaga.js file:

```
function(doc) {
    return null;
}
```

This transform must exclude everything, but anything were copied. I just need to filter my documents by condition like this:

```
if(!doc['SagaDocId'].startsWith('TestSaga/')) {
    return null;
}
```

How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Note that --transform-file works only with import. [Documentation of import/export](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/java/server/administration/exporting-and-importing-data)